# Checkbox update value only works on false to true, not on true to false, React, mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I use a state as a form to update boolean data in MongoDB.
Only works when the value is updated from false to true, not work from true to false.
Is there somebody who can help me out? Thanks a lot.

Here is my state as a form

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    cases: false,
    mtrl: false,
    cst: false,
    mp: false,
    po: false,
  });
```

Here is onChange func

```
 const onChangeCB = (e) => {
    if (!e.target.checked) {
      setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: false });
    } else if (e.target.checked) {
      setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: true });
    }
  };
```

The checkbox

```
   <input
        type='checkbox'
        name='cases'
        checked={cases === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{' '}
      Case{' '}
      <input
        type='checkbox'
        name='mtrl'
        checked={mtrl === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{' '}
      Material{' '}
      <input
        type='checkbox'
        name='cst'
        checked={cst === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{' '}
      Cunsumption{' '}
      <input
        type='checkbox'
        name='mp'
        checked={mp === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{' '}
      Material Price{' '}
      <input
        type='checkbox'
        name='po'
        checked={po === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{' '}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As per the example it all looks good, can you produce the same error on codesandbox or stackblitz, so we can help you better way?

Comment: Hey Vivek, thanks for ask. It works alright at client, the form is also good, the form also got textbox, all the stuff updated well, except the checkbox. When I PUT the form to MongoDB, only  "false" can be updated to "true", and "true" can't be updated to "false".

Answer (score 0):

You are storing state in object, so in your input, the value of `checked` should be `user.cases` (for example)

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-issue-fix-wiqgb)

**Code snippet**

```js
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    cases: false,
    mtrl: false,
    cst: false,
    mp: false,
    po: false
  });
  const onChangeCB = e => {
    if (!e.target.checked) {
      setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: false });
    } else if (e.target.checked) {
      setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: true });
    }
  };
  console.log("user", user);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="cases"
        checked={user.cases === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{" "}
      Case{" "}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="mtrl"
        checked={user.mtrl === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{" "}
      Material{" "}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="cst"
        checked={user.cst === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{" "}
      Cunsumption{" "}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="mp"
        checked={user.mp === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{" "}
      Material Price{" "}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="po"
        checked={user.po === true}
        onChange={onChangeCB}
      />{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note - You can also consider to write the onChange in a simplified way like below:

```js
const onChangeCB = (e) => {
  const target = e.target;
  setUser((prev) => ({ ...prev, [target.name]: !prev[target.name] }));
};
```

Comment: Hey gdh, thanks for a clear answer, I forgot to mention that I 've pulled the variables out from the user. I've tried, but still work as before, can't update from true to false

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change a boolean value is change to the opposite. It´s a toggle function. If you have a boolean state.. you should have a onChange function using ! operator. setState : !state

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for answer, I'm still trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const onChangeCB = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: checked ? true : false });
};
```

Comment: Hi Tejal, thanks for the answer. My state does work as expected when the checkbox checked, its value is "true", when not checked, its value is "false". However, if I PUT the form to MongoDB, only the state that value is "false" will be updated to "true", and the state in value "true" can't be updated to "false".

Comment: try adding async to onChangeCB method and await to setUser

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Hey Tejal, I've tried async to the onChange and setUser, but still, it works same, when 'true' needs to be updated to 'false', everything ok, but when it updating 'false' to 'true', the update will not work, the backend report nothing and the value not be updated in the database.

Comment: Is it working as expected in onChangeCB? Means if you add console before setUser for received details and after setUser for updated details then is it giving expected value?

Comment: Hi Tejal, Yes onChangeCB gives me the expected value I want, you can see the 4th figure with an orange label, the checkbox works as well as the form.

Comment: While assigning value to checked attribute, directly place the user property "checked={user.propName}" instead of "checked={cases === true}"